# Variable substitution in TCL heredoc

Tags: tcl, heredoc

```
exec -- sftp user@127.0.0.1 {<<
get $filename
quit}
```

How can i substitute $filename?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get variable substitution, use double quotes instead of braces. Standard Tcl rule, though maybe surprising to you in this situation. (I recommend putting the `<<` outside as its own argument as I think it is clearer that way.)

```
exec -- sftp user@127.0.0.1 << "
get $filename
quit"
```

You can also use the `subst` command. Sometimes that is clearer; it's largely equivalent (except for some *very* fine niceties that don't matter too much unless you're doing large templated documents).

```
exec -- sftp user@127.0.0.1 << [subst {
    get $filename
    quit
}]
```